# How can I replace various columns in a tibble using select?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I try to replace all columns selected using `select` by data of the same size.
A reproducible example is

```
library(tidyverse)
iris = as_data_frame(iris)
temp = cbind( runif(nrow(iris)), runif(nrow(iris)), runif(nrow(iris)), runif(nrow(iris)))
select(iris, -one_of("Petal.Length"))  = temp
```

Then I get the error

> Error in select(iris, -one_of("Petal.Length")) = temp : could not find
>   function "select"

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Not as convenient but `iris[,!grepl("Petal.Length",colnames(iris))]=temp`works

Comment: it is not that R does not find function `select` but rather `select<-`. The behaviour which you want à la `rownames` is different than what `select` can do.

Comment: @Haboryme thank you. I know - with the usual data.frame approach this is the way to got. I just thought that there is a "tidy" way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to bind columns of two data frames, so you can simply use `bind_cols()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris <- as_tibble(iris)
temp <- tibble(r1 = runif(nrow(iris)), r2 = runif(nrow(iris)), r3 = runif(nrow(iris)), r4 = runif(nrow(iris)))

select(iris, -Petal.Length) %>% bind_cols(temp)
# or use:
# bind_cols(iris, temp) %>% select(-Petal.Length)
```

which gives you:

```
# A tibble: 150 × 8
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Width Species        r1        r2         r3        r4
          <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1           5.1         3.5         0.2  setosa 0.7208566 0.1367070 0.04314771 0.4909396
2           4.9         3.0         0.2  setosa 0.4101884 0.4795735 0.75318182 0.1463689
3           4.7         3.2         0.2  setosa 0.6270065 0.5425814 0.26599432 0.1467248
4           4.6         3.1         0.2  setosa 0.8001282 0.4691908 0.73060637 0.0792256
5           5.0         3.6         0.2  setosa 0.5663895 0.4745482 0.65088630 0.5360953
6           5.4         3.9         0.4  setosa 0.8813042 0.1560600 0.41734507 0.2582568
7           4.6         3.4         0.3  setosa 0.5046977 0.9555570 0.22118401 0.9246906
8           5.0         3.4         0.2  setosa 0.5283764 0.4730212 0.24982471 0.6313071
9           4.4         2.9         0.2  setosa 0.5976045 0.4717439 0.14270551 0.2149888
10          4.9         3.1         0.1  setosa 0.3919660 0.5125420 0.95001067 0.5259598
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Comment: You can also bind first and then select, see my updated example.

Comment: `bind`  != replace; if binding is what OP wants, then it is advicable to correct the question...

Comment: Technically, you select columns of one data frame and combine / bind them with columns of the other data frame. Of course, "exact" replacement would also require to check column indices of the removed columns, and reorder the combine data frame so the new columns are also at the positions of the removed columns (which matters when removed columns are randomly spread).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `->` to assign the output to 'temp'

```
select(iris, -one_of("Petal.Length"))  -> temp
```

Comment: thank you but I want to have temp in the tibble and not the columns of the tibble in temp.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` paradigma you could use:

```
dplyr::mutate_at(iris, vars(-one_of("Petal.Length")), .funs = funs(runif))
```

Although the above sample produces the behaviour with random numbers, it will probably not suit your needs - i suppose you want match features and rows to that one in `temp`.

It can be done by trasforming iris and temp into long format and the join and replace data accordingly with `*join` methods for example.

Comment: thank you. I just want to replace the columns in the tibble with the values in temp.

Comment: Then @Haboryme approach in the comment is the most straght forward way to do it. (so why do you want to use `select` in the first place?)

Comment: I want to replace the columns and as the tidyverse approeach is heavily advertised I thought I would try to stick to it.